# stl::map assert

Tags: c++, stl

I am running following piece of code on VS 2008

```
 typedef map<int ,string> ListofName;
 Class abc
 {
    ListofName m_List;
    ListofName  GetList(){ &m_List;}
 }

 ThredProc(void* args)
 {
     abc* pabc = (abs*)args;

     for( ListofName:: iterator itrList = GetList()->begin(); 
                  itrList != GetList()->end();
                  itrList++)
     {
       // some operation
     }
```

}

when the list is empty the code is crashing when itrList ++ is executing.

Comment: Please show code that's much closer to the actual code.

Comment: Can you give a simple example that actually compiles and reproduces the problem? Your code here is all wrong.

Comment: When the list is empty, `itrList++` should never execute. How is your real code different?

Comment: -1: The code you posted doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

The following method definition

```
ListofName  GetList(){ &m_List;}
```

is simply wrong ! Replace it with

```
ListofName&  GetList(){ return m_List;}
```

And use it as a reference to an object and not a pointer to an object, meaning use "." instead of "->"

```
 for( ListofName:: iterator itrList = GetList().begin(); 
              itrList != GetList().end();
              itrList++)
```

I suggest you read a bit more about c++ fundamentals.

Comment: I tried your suggestion its not working.

Comment: If you want more advice, show us more code. Note that my actual suggestion is to learn more about c++...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef std::map<int ,std::string> ListofName;

class abc{
public:
    ListofName m_List;
    ListofName&  GetList(){ return m_List;}
 };

void testfunction(void* args){
     abc* pabc = (abc*)args;

     for( ListofName::iterator itrList = pabc->GetList().begin(); 
                  itrList != pabc->GetList().end();
                  itrList++)
     {
       // some operation
     }

}
```